# Why are the back and home buttons not appearing by default in my jQuery Mobile pages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The back and home buttons are not appearing in the headers of my jQuery Mobile application, even though I did not suppress them. Why? Here is how a page looks like in my app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <title>My jQuery Mobile App</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Look Up a Stock</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->    
        <div data-role="content">
            Code to look up a stock.
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&copy; 2012</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Adding Back buttons**
>
> jQuery Mobile has a feature to automatically
> create and append "back" buttons to any header, though it is disabled
> by default. This is primarily useful in chromeless installed
> applications, such as those running in a native app web view. The
> framework automatically generates a "back" button on a header when the
> page plugin's addBackBtn option is true. This can also be set via
> markup if the page div has a data-add-back-btn="true" attribute.
>
> If you use the attribute data-rel="back" on an anchor, any clicks on
> that anchor will mimic the back button, going back one history entry
> and ignoring the anchor's default href. This is particularly useful
> when linking back to a named page, such as a link that says "home", or
> when generating "back" buttons with JavaScript, such as a button to
> close a dialog. When using this feature in your source markup, **be sure
> to provide a meaningful href that actually points to the URL of the
> referring page (this will allow the feature to work for users in
> C-Grade browsers**. Also, please keep in mind that if you just want a
> reverse transition without actually going back in history, you should
> use the data-direction="reverse" attribute instead.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html*

This used to be turned on by default but it made more sense for more people to leave it off by default.

Your HTML could change to this:

```
<div data-add-back-btn="true" data-role="page">
    ...
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nHgu7/1/

You can also bind to the `mobileinit` event to set the default value for `addBackBtn`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
      $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nHgu7/2/

*Source: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-t-get-mobile-addbackbtn-to-work*

## Update

You can automatically add a home button to each page like this:

```
//attach an event handler to any `data-role="page"` element at any time for the `pageinit` event
//(the event that fires when the page is about to be initialized)
​$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {

    //check for a `data-role="header"` element to add a home button to
    var $header = $(this).children('[data-role="header"]');
    if ($header.length) {

        //create a link with a `href` attribute and a `class` attribute,
        //then turn it into a jQuery Mobile button widget
        $header.append($('<a />', { class : 'ui-btn-right', href : '#zero' }).buttonMarkup({ icon: "home", iconpos : "notext" }));
    }        
});​​​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nHgu7/3/

And if you just add an `if` statement that checks for the homepage's ID you can add a home button to all but the homepage:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {

    //check to see if this is the homepage, if so do nothing
    if (this.id != 'home') {
        var $header = $(this).children('[data-role="header"]');
        if ($header.length) {
            $header.append($('<a />', { class : 'ui-btn-right', href : '#zero' }).buttonMarkup({ icon: "home", iconpos : "notext" }));
        }    
    }    
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nHgu7/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That document and example was helpful. I got the back button working. Do you have an idea as to where †he documentation talks about adding a home button too (the little house icon)?

Comment: Never mind, I discovered that `<a href="/" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-rel="home">` adds a home button. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidFaux I added an **update** on how to automatically add a home button to each page.